# Dynamically filling rectangles in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a program in WPF that simulates a 2D Rubik's Cube. In the Form Window, I added rectangles that represent each of the six sides and I named them based on their side. The problem is, that I can't get the Colors to display on *any* square.

```
private void Main()
    {
        switch (cubeL[0,0])
        {
            case "Blue":
                //var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
                //var brush = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FF00008B");
                L1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkBlue);
                break;

            case "Orange":
                //var converter1 = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
                //var brush1 = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter1.ConvertFromString("#FFFFA500");
                L1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get the color Orange to display on one side, but I can't get it to work, and I've read *everywhere* that you just use:

```
rectanglename.Fill(Color)
```

so I think it's a problem with my XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MonoBrick.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Cube" Height="611.767" Width="624.5" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    <Rectangle x:Name="L6" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="91,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="7,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" AutomationProperties.Name="L1"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L4" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="7,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L7" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="7,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="91,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="49,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="49,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L8" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="49,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="L9" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="91,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F6" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="223,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F4" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="139,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F7" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="139,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="223,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="181,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="181,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F8" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="181,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R6" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="356,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="272,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R4" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="272,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R7" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="272,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="356,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="314,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="314,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R8" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="314,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R9" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="356,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B6" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="488,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="404,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B4" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="404,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B7" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="404,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="488,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="446,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="446,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B8" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="446,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="B9" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="488,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="139,132,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="F9" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="223,212,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U6" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="223,45,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U4" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="139,45,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U7" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="139,85,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="223,5,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="181,45,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="181,5,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U8" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="181,85,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="139,5,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="U9" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="223,85,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D6" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="223,297,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D4" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="139,297,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D7" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="139,337,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="223,258,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="181,297,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="181,258,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D8" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="181,337,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="139,258,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="D9" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="223,337,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
</Grid>
```

Maybe I just need to change the namespace, or fix a really stupid mistake, I'm still learning C#, so any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing more of the C# code, I'm wondering if that Main() method is being called *before* the view has rendered. The fill colours you've set would be ignored and effectively "overwritten" by the XAML. Try handling the window's `Loaded` event and setting the fill colours from in there instead.

Comment: @AndrewStephens thanks, it worked. I put the cube arrays outside the `Main()` so I could call them anywhere, so now that it's inside the load event, how do I call it from anywhere? (I'm still learning)

Comment: Putting the code in the `Loaded` event handler was just to prove my theory that you were calling the Main() method too soon (before the window has loaded & rendered). WPF is an event-driven framework so you would *usually* execute code in event handlers, e.g. a button click. These kinds of events start working once the window has been loaded/rendered, so you could (for example) call your Main() method from one of these events and it should work fine.

Comment: If you just want to call Main() when the window first loads (to initialise your rubics cube colours) then calling it from the Loaded event handler is probably okay. It would be useful if you could edit your initial question to explain more about what you are trying to achieve, and where else you want to call Main() from.

Comment: @AndrewStephens I wanted to make it so that I can press a button to execute a move without having to reload the colors of the squares (the colors for each side are stored in 6 arrays.) so that it's dynamic

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking to do, but why not initialise the entire cube within the Loaded event (or a "start game" button click). This would involve initialising the arrays (e.g. random colours), then using these values to set the Fill colour of every corresponding <Rectangle>. In your "execute move" button click, after working out which squares have been affected by the move, update the relevant array entries then use these values to set the Fill colour of the <Rectangle>'s affected by the move (or it may be easier to just update all 54 rectangles after every move).

Comment: @AndrewStephens I want the squares to update automatically, based on the values in the arrays. If I put everything inside of the loaded event, and filling the squares in `Main()` and press a button to change the values in the arrays, will the rectangles automatically update?

Comment: To get this automatic updating, you'll need to learn about WPF binding. In a nutshell you'd create a class that represents a square (exposing a Color property), and instantiate one for each square on the cube, probably storing them all in an array. You then "bind" each <Rectangle>'s Fill colour to its respective object's property (programmatically creating the controls makes this easier). When you change the Color property of one of these objects, its "bound" Fill colour will update automatically. For this to work the object has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.